# Can we change a function's implemetion?

Tags: java, reflection

There's a framework ,contains 4 functions like:

```
public long t1(){
    return 10;
}

public long t2(){
    return 20;
}

public long t3() {
    return 30;
}

public long t4(){
    return (t2()-t1());
}
```

can we change the implementaion of t4 to :

```
 public long t4(){
        return (t3() - t1());
    }
```

add: we can't change the implemention of the existing framework.

add2: this class of the framework is not directly used by user, so I can't extends it, and override the method.

Comment: Why don't you create your own method returning `t3() - t1()`

Comment: try method overriding? extend the class and override just the method t4()?

Comment: In the language: no. With bytecode manipulation: yes (depending). One such library that allows such is [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/). However, I would consider a Proxy (or Facade) instead, if such is possible.

Answer (score 1):

With only object-oriented Java or reflection, you will never achieve exactly what you are asking.

In fact, changing a methods implementation is changing the static part of your class. This can not be achieved after class loading.

But how to change the static part before the classes are loaded? The answer is: aspect orientation. Then you can change the static part of a class at source time, compile time or class load time.

As you do not own the source, I think you are using a pre-compiled library. So you will have to do it at class load time. This is done by a load time weaver, for example with AspectJ.

I recommend adding a surround advice to shortcircuit the current method and execute the statements you want.

Summarize: use AspectJ with a surround advice on that method.

Answer (score 0):

We can override the existing method by a new one with the concept of `method-overriding`.

```
 class Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Animals can move");
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Dogs can walk and run");
   }
}

public class TestDog{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Animal a = new Animal(); // Animal reference and object
      Animal b = new Dog(); // Animal reference but Dog object

      a.move();// runs the method in Animal class

      b.move();//Runs the method in Dog class
   }
}
```

Comment: the class is not directly used ,so I can't extends and override the method.